# Which .XML file are using for Insert Link button of General Link field in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Can anybody tell me which .xml file are using for Insert Link button of General Link field in Sitecore 7.2.

I have tried to update below files but all are not affecting -

Sitecore.Shell.Application.Dialogs.InternalLink-InternalLink.xml
Sitecore.Shell.Application.Dialogs.InsertLink-InsertLink.xml

Sitecore.Shell.Application.Buckets - BucketInternalLink.xml

Sitecore.Shell.Application.Buckets - InsertLink.xml

I think under Buckets folder files are using in case of General Link field with Search

I have tried for all

If I am updating other files like

Sitecore.Shell.Application.Dialogs.ExternalLink - ExternalLink.xml

then it's showing updates in Sitecore but in case of insert link no one files are working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitecore 7.2 the XML Insert Link Dialog is replaced by the new SPEAK UI Dialog. The actual url of the insert link dialog is located on

```
http://[yourdomain]/sitecore/client/applications/dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog
```

The actual file is located in the core database under: /sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog.

From there you can navigate to the appropriate renderings and modify them (which might affect other windows.

If you want to enable the old style InsertLink that uses the InsertLink.xml you can disable it from /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Speak.config and remove the following line:

```
<override dialogUrl="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx" with="/sitecore/client/applications/dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this information Can you please let me know how we can get that which library it's using and how we can override with our custom class

Answer (score 2):

check out my blogpost about fixing the internal link. It might prove difficult to extend but it is possible. At least I have been able to override the class and pass the preLoadPath.

http://reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/fixing-sitecore-7-internal-link-with-speak/